# block url direct access to index.php except when user clicked on the link on another specific html file such as index.html

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

**first of all sorry for my english**

I want to limit direct access to index.php file in Wordpress, like when user type www.example.com/index.php in URL bar.

I want that file only opened when user viewed index.html
on the index.html i use JAVASCRIPT to redirect after few seconds to index.php

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be done with mod rewrite via .htaccess file..  Assuming your web server has it installed, (most do)..   create or edit the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
# If not from
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?example\.com/index\.html [NC]
# Go to
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/index.html [L]
```

note that HTTP_REFERER is a value provided by the viewers browser and can be spoofed and/or edited, so not 100% reliable

Answer (score 1):

You can use some PHP code for this on index.php

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'www.example.com/index.html')
{
    header("location: www.example.com/some_page.php");
    die();
}
```

This code is basically saying if the page you were on before isnt `index.html` then redirect to some other page, using this you can further customise it to your needs with a little PHP knowledge.